# Why does PhpStorm formatting break SQL files exported from phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, phpstorm

Hi Stackoverflow experts :)

im exporting files from phpmyadmin and using phpstorm for PHP coding. 
On commit I reformat files to achieve consistency.

When I commit sql files it reformats them, which breaks sql code

e.g. 2014-10-13 becomes 2014 - 10 - 13
'reset-password' becomes 'reset - PASSWORD'
html code in export breaks in middle of html -> < p > or linebreak in ;nbsp &

Any ideas how i can disable reformatting for SQL files?

regards
Tibor

Comment: You cannot .. unless you disable automatic code reformat on commit and will do it manually **before** committing. In any case -- the way the code is got reformatted seems to be wrong. 1) Please post an example of such file (whole file, not just part of it). 2) PhpStorm version used?

Comment: It happens with any newest version. Code was cleaned up already manually.

So then its a bug. Will try to file it with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per information from comment it isnt possible to disable SQL code formatting independent of PHP.

Workaround:
- commit SQL files separately and disable reformatting.